# Separate declaration of functions in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there a way (maybe some pragma or extension (I'm using **GHC**)) that allow to declare different patterns of function separately?

For example, I **can** do that:

```
fun1 1 = "1"
fun1 2 = "a"
fun1 3 = "4"
fun1 4 = "3"
```

But I **can't** do that:

```
fun1 1 = "1"
fun1 2 = "a"
fun1 3 = "4"

a = 3 -- Just some code here.

fun1 4 = "3"
```

i. e. I need something to remove this restriction.

I need it in some kind of "game", where the previous code **can't** be edited.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I honestly doubt that you NEED this feature.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @jwodder Yes I NEED. I play in special sort of game, where I must add new functionality WITHOUT editing previous code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. Multiple definitions like this are just syntax sugar over `case` and thus are not terrifically robust syntactic abstractions. It's just not normally necessary.

You may have luck using the [`haskell-src` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src) to parse Haskell code and build your incremental interface for your game.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help feeling that if this were allowed, folk would write rather messy code.

Unless there's an important structural reason, it'd be better to stick with the usual valid syntax - it's easier to understand if the definition is all in one place.

However, perhaps it would be better to structure it differently to achieve what you want:

- You could use [Data.Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.1/docs/Data-Map.html) to build up several submaps in different parts of your code, then glue them all together at some appropriate stage.
- You could keep these definitions in a sort of configuration file or files, and read them in as your game initialised. Your users might like the ease of editing the game this way.
- You could store your data in a more Haskell-friendly way

  - You could serialise it using the [binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) package, which is fast, and read it in at runtime.
  - You could use Yesod's backend-agnostic [Persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent)
  - Too many other options here
- You could use a union type (like `Either`) for your input to `fun1`, and then distribute the definition about the code, but write a unified function that checks the input and tags it according to category.

It's hard to know what's best without some knowledge of what you're trying to do, but slackening the sytnax rules doesn't feel like a good step forward.

Comment: I meant that I'm playing in some sort of game, where I must add something new to program, but can't edit previous code.
Thank you anyway!